# Adding two default gateways in Debian interfaces file

Tags: debian, networking, routing

This is my interfaces file:

```
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
   address 192.168.1.10
   netmask 255.255.255.0
   gateway 192.168.1.1

auto eth1
iface eth1 inet static
   address 192.168.2.10
   netmask 255.255.255.0
   gateway 192.168.2.1
```

If I restart networking daemon I get this error: `eth1 is not up`. I want two default gateways [to achieve what is mentioned in the accepted answer to the question here](https://superuser.com/questions/341030/i-have-both-cable-and-dsl-at-home-how-do-i-put-that-to-good-use). This is how my routing table should be:

```
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
default         192.168.1.1     0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
default         192.168.2.1     0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth1
192.168.1.0     *               255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth0
192.168.2.0     *               255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth1
```

I got the above table by using `ifconfig` and `route add default gw` commands. But I want to do it with the `/etc/network/interfaces` file. How can I do it?

Update1:

```
iface eth0 inet static
    address 192.168.1.10
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    up ip route del 192.168.1.0/24
    post-up ip route add 192.168.1.0/24 dev eth0 metric 1
    up route add default gw 192.168.1.1 metric 1
```

Comment: As long as you don't care how your traffic goes out.  On Solaris and earlier Linux versions this was done in a Round-Robin fashion

Comment: Your interfaces file looks correct.  Usually, DHCP is much more convenient today and that is what I used in this circumstance.  You can give specific MAC addresses a set IP address in the DHCP server's settings.

Comment: Just a side note, NetworkManager recently added more extensive support for route metrics. It handles them automatically or you can set them manually. It might be a more convenient way or you might want to file a feature request for your tool.

Comment: Also you might want to add details on why you want to have two default routes at all. I can only guess that two routes with different metrics will *not* work as you expect.

Comment: The interfaces file allows setting a metric. There should be no need to add routes manually using up and post-up

Answer (score 11):

This /etc/network/interfaces works for me on 2.6.32-40 Ubuntu 10.04 LTS:

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
    address 192.168.1.10
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    network 192.168.1.0
    broadcast 192.168.1.254
    post-up route add default gw 192.168.1.1 metric 1
    pre-down route del default gw 192.168.1.1

auto eth1
iface eth1 inet static
    address 192.168.2.10
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    network 192.168.2.0
    broadcast 192.168.2.254
    post-up route add default gw 192.168.2.1 metric 2
    pre-down route del default gw 192.168.2.1
```

I get two default routes:

```
root@gamla:/etc/network# route -n
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
192.168.2.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth1
192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth0
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     1000   0        0 eth0
0.0.0.0         192.168.1.1     0.0.0.0         UG    1      0        0 eth0
0.0.0.0         192.168.2.1     0.0.0.0         UG    2      0        0 eth1
```

Note the metric. Did I understand your question?

Comment: The network and gateway associated with `eth0` should apper first as it's the primary network and gateway. What is the output of `netstat -anr` or just `route` commands in your setup?

Comment: I edited, adding metric parameters to get the desired route order. My system has a number of other interfaces that I edited out of the output, and my interface names are not ethX, so I am not 100% sure that my solution will work for you. Try it and let me know the results.

Comment: Adding metric for default gateways works. But how can I add metric for routes? My routing table has a class B subnet which should come before my another class A subnet. Specifying `metric 3` from debian `ifmetric` package did not work for me.

Comment: The kernel stores the metric but does not use it to route. To use the metric, you need to run a routing daemon such as quagga (was zebra) or bird.

Comment: This adds the metric `post-up ip route add 192.168.1.0/24 dev eth0 metric 1` But the networking daemon by using intefaces file adds the same route with 0 metric before that. So I have to add this before my above mentioned command: `up ip route del 192.168.1.0/24`. Can it be made simpler? I have updated my question with reference to this query.

Comment: @EliRosencruft can you cite a reference plz?

Comment: @EliRosencruft: Do you have any reason to broadcast on `254` instead of `255`? I spent an hour understanding why your great answer was not working at my place. My router has its IP ending in `254`!

Comment: The interfaces file allows setting the metric (now?). Please update your answere to use that instead of post-up/pre-down.