# Add network eth with a separate gateway

Tags: debian, networking

OS: Debian

Currently I have only 1 network connection setup (br0).

I'd like to connect a second network connection (eth3) to a separate network/gateway.

Everything should continue to be sent through eth0, except if I specifically choose to send a request out via eth1 (such as CURL request specifying eth1)

*Note that eth2 is used as br0 bridge for a number of KVM virtual machines.*

**UPDATED:** I added some routes and updates to the interfaces file:
Here is my current interfaces file.

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto br0
iface br0 inet static
  address 192.168.1.121
  network 192.168.1.0
  netmask 255.255.255.0
  broadcast 192.168.1.255
  gateway 192.168.1.1
  bridge_ports eth2
  bridge_stp on
  bridge_fd 0
  bridge_maxwait 0
  post-up ip route add 192.168.1.0/24 dev br0 metric 1
  post-up route add default gw 192.168.1.1 metric 1
  pre-down route del default gw 192.168.1.1

auto eth3
iface eth3 inet static
  address 192.168.0.121
  netmask 255.255.255.0
  broadcast 192.168.0.255
  gateway 191.168.0.1
  post-up ip route add 192.168.0.0/24 dev eth3 metric 2
  post-up route add default gw 192.168.0.1 metric 2
  pre-down route del default gw 192.168.0.1
```

However when I try to restart networking service is gives this error (also gives this error when trying to use `ifup eth3`

> RTNETLINK answers: File exists
>
> Failed to bring up eth3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know which IP addresses you will be connecting to via `eth1` then you should set up routing.

Your default gateway will remain `eth0` so all traffic will go there by default, however, any traffic sent to specific networks or IP addresses will go through `eth1`.

*Check your current routing tables using the `iproute2` package:*

```
$ ip route list
default via gateway 192.168.1.1 dev eth0
gateway 192.168.1.0/24 dev eth0  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.1.121
```

*Set a static route using the gateway from `eth1` to get to `unix.stackexchange.com`:*

> ip route add (remote_network) via (remote_connecting_gatway) dev (local_outgoing_interface)

```
$ ip route add 198.252.206.16/32 via 192.168.0.1  dev eth1
```

*Check the new routing table:*

```
$ ip route list
default via gateway 192.168.1.1 dev eth0
gateway 192.168.1.0/24 dev eth0  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.1.121
198.252.206.16 via 192.168.0.1 dev eth1
```

*Test the new route:*

```
$ ip route get 198.252.206.16
198.252.206.16 via 192.168.0.1 dev eth1  src 192.168.0.121
cache
```

*Delete the route:*

```
$  ip route del 198.252.206.16/32 via 192.168.0.1  dev eth1
```

*Make this static route persistant through a reboot:*

Add the following entries to the `/etc/network/interfaces` file:

```
auto eth1
iface eth1 inet static
address 192.168.0.121
network 192.168.0.0
netmask 255.255.255.0
broadcast 192.168.0.255
post-up ip route add 198.252.206.16/32 via 192.168.0.1  dev eth1
pre-down ip route del 198.252.206.16/32 via 192.168.0.1  dev eth1
```

**Notice the `post-up` and `pre-down entries`.**

*Restart networking:*

```
$ /etc/init.d/networking restart
```

**Note:**

If you do **NOT** know the IP addresses you will go to, then you need to add an additional routing table to contain the second default routes.

This is covered in detail on [Two Default Gateways on One System](http://www.thomas-krenn.com/en/wiki/Two_Default_Gateways_on_One_System).

**References**

[man ip](http://manpages.debian.org/cgi-bin/man.cgi?query=ip&apropos=0&sektion=0&manpath=Debian+7.0+wheezy&format=html&locale=en)
[man interfaces](http://manpages.debian.org/cgi-bin/man.cgi?query=interfaces&apropos=0&sektion=0&manpath=Debian+7.0+wheezy&format=html&locale=en)
[Configure static routing on Debian](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/configuring-static-routes-in-debian-or-red-hat-linux-systems.html)
[Two Default Gateways on One System](http://www.thomas-krenn.com/en/wiki/Two_Default_Gateways_on_One_System)

Comment: Note that I don't know the specific remote destination for all eth1 requests.  For eth1 requests I would use CURLOPT_TIMEOUT 'eth1'.  I have updated to interfaces config to include routes, but getting "Failed to bring up eth1"

Comment: That was a rather large caveat! You will need to remove the gateway entry from `eth1` if you are using the routing method.

Comment: So the 192.168.0.1 gateway does not need to specified as gateway in the interfaces file?

Comment: Yes - added the additional details

Answer (score 0):

When you have two default gw you could add a higher metric value on eth1 to avoid other than specified traffic over that interface.
I think that this post have your answer.
[Adding two default gateways in Debian interfaces file](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/35713/adding-two-default-gateways-in-debian-interfaces-file)